# Problems while displaying nvd3 pieChart in a pop up window?

Tags: javascript, charts, delay, nvd3.js, popupwindow

I am opening nvd3 pieChart in a popup window. I create popup window like this:

```
function openPopup(html,pos,style) {
    var newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.document.write(html);
    return newWindow;
}

function openChartPopup(chartID,chartTitle) {
    divId = "div" + chartID;
    html = "<p>"+chartTitle+"</p><div  id= \""+divId+"\"><svg id=\""+chartID+"\"></svg></div>";
    newWindow = openPopup(html,"_blank","");
    return d3.select(newWindow.document.getElementById(chartID));
}
```

then I create a pieChart using following code:

```
de_select = openChartPopup("test_chart","TEst Chart");
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true)
      .growOnHover(true);
    de_select.datum(exampleData());
    de_select.style({"width":"400px", "height":"500px"});
    de_select.transition().duration(350);
    de_select.call(chart);
    nv.addGraph(chart);
```

I execute the above code on button click which opens a chart in pop up but sometimes it doesn't appear correctly and looks like this:
[image]

When I switch tabs and focus on pop window again it appears correctly as:
[image]

However, all chart properties still doesn't work fine, for example "growOnHover" but the same code works fine when I display chart in a normal html page instead of popup, I guess it has something to do with popup window, Is it the problem with NVD3,? Can anyone point out the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

This will update the chart when the window is resized. Which may happen in the case of popup window.

I am not sure how you open the popup window. You could use

```
newWindow = window.open("",title, "width=400,height=500");
newWindow.document.write(html);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for your comment. I updated the answer

Comment: @programmer1490, I am using the same code as you mentioned openPopup is a function, I have updated the post you can see. Moreover, I have tried your suggestion of window resize but it didn't work

Comment: This solution works when you are opening a popup in a new window by defining "width=400,height=500" else popup open as  a new tab and resize doesn't effect. For the time being I am opening the whole new window not just a separate tab and it's working fine, However, I still wonders if it's possible to resolve the issue when popup is just a new tab and not a new window :/