# Weird looking NVD3 MultiBarChart on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, charts, scale, nvd3.js

When resizing the browser window of IE my MultiBarCharts look weird:

[image]

On Chrome they look just fine.

I'm using **nvd3 version 1.8.4** and tested it on IE 11. Is this a common issue?

Comment: Did you call resize and check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829503/problems-while-displaying-nvd3-piechart-in-a-pop-up-window

Comment: yes, but that didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of digging I found out that the issue was caused by some lines of css from **angular-material**. I have no idea why but once I removed the following lines of code the bars displayed correctly:

```
   @media (min-width: 960px) {
    md-menu-content {
        min-width: 96px;
    }
    md-menu-content[width="3"] {}
}
```

What really confuses me is that I'm not even using md-menu-content within my app... If somebody knows how my issue is related to the css of angular  material, please let me know.